# How do I publish an App outside the App Store

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS Development and started on a few projects and wanted to make some money from them. But I don't want to publish the App to the App Store since it isn't perfect yet. Once I get some more users and receive feedback I will be able to make it better and eventually good enough to publish it to the App Store. Do you guys have any place I could publish my app and make some money from it?

Answer (score 2):

Before submitting the App to Appstore you can use the TestFlight for your feedback testing, For this, you need to purchase  $99/yr [Apple Developer program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/). What is Testflight? Go through [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight.html)

> TestFlight makes it easy to invite users to test your apps and collect
>   valuable feedback before you release them on the App Store. You can
>   invite up to 2,000 testers using just their email address.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks I will try your suggested method! Thanks for the help!